# Method of undetermined coefficients, multiplying for a higher term

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I got the following problem, and I think im using the method wrong.

$\ddot x = x + ate^{-t}$, the homogeneous equation is $x_{h}=c_{1}e^{t}+c_{2}e^{-t}$

What I would do for the particular solution is just use $(b_{0}+b_{1}t)e^{-t}$ but Im pretty sure it does not work and I have no idea why. Then I guess I have to upgrade a $t$, I mean $x_{p}=(b_{0}t+b_{1}t^{2})e^{-t}$ and well, this works pretty well, but again I dont know why and I dont know in which cases do I have to do this.

What is suspect is that if I dont multiply for a higher term, the RHS might be equal to some term of the homogeneous equation.

Another examples should be $\ddot x -2\dot x +2x = e^{t}sin(t)$. The $x_{h}=c_{1}e^{t}cos(t) + c_{2}e^{t}sin(t)$, and the particular solution should look like $x_{p}=e^{t}sin(t) + e^{t}cos(t)$. Since $e^{t}sin(t)$ looks like $c_{2}e^{t}sin(t)$ in the homogeneous equation, should I multiply it for $t$ as well?

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: $x_p(t)=t(At+B)e^{-t}$ should work fine

Comment: I know haha I tested it, but I dont know why does it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to try $x(t)_p=(At+B)e^{-t}$
But since $e^{-t}$ is already a solution of multiplicity 1 of the homogeneous equation you need to multiply by $t$. Therefore you have to try $$x(t)_p=t(At+B)e^{-t}$$

Or you can make things easy 
and substitute $$x=z(t)e^{-t} \implies z''-2z'=at$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your asnwer, now in this example, $\ddot x -2\dot x +2x = e^{t}sin(t)$. The $x_{h}=c_{1}e^{t}cos(t) + c_{2}e^{t}sin(t)$, and the particular solution should look like $x_{p}=e^{t}sin(t) + e^{t}cos(t)$. Since $e^{t}sin(t)$ looks like $c_{2}e^{t}sin(t)$ in the homogeneous equation, should I multiply it for $t$ as well?

Comment: yes you need to multiply by  a factor t since its already a solution of the homogeneous equation . @asd123

Comment: remember by the way that sine and cosine function are just exponential function (Euler formula) so it's the same as your original equation. @asd123